# Repetitive writing in output using list of characters - python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

In a file, I have some characters to be substituted.

letters = ["B", "Z", "J", "U", "O"]

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(inFile, "fasta"):
    for letter in letters:
        if letters in str(record.seq):
            print record.id 
            record.seq = str(record.seq).replace(letter, "X")
            outFile.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (record.description, record.seq))
        else:
            outFile.write(">%s\n%s\n" % (record.description, record.seq))
            #pass
```

The problem is that the output looks like this, writing the outputs as many characters I have in letters:

```
> >ID:WP_004160595.1|Erwinia_amylovora_01SFR-BO|01SFR-BO|50S_ribosomal_protei..|630|NZ_CAPA01000010(58437):26053-26682:-1
> MIGLVGKKVGMTRIFTEDGVSIPVTVIEIEANRVTQVKGLENDGYTAIQVTTGAKKANRVTKPAAGHFAKAGVEAGRGLWEFRTAEGAEFTVGQSINVDIFADVKKVDVTGTSKGKGFAGTVKRWNFRTQDATHGNSLSHRVPGSIGQNQTPGKVFKGKKMAGQLGNERVTVQSLDVVRVDAERNLLLVKGAVPGATGSDLIVKPAVKA
> >ID:WP_004160595.1|Erwinia_amylovora_01SFR-BO|01SFR-BO|50S_ribosomal_protei..|630|NZ_CAPA01000010(58437):26053-26682:-1
> MIGLVGKKVGMTRIFTEDGVSIPVTVIEIEANRVTQVKGLENDGYTAIQVTTGAKKANRVTKPAAGHFAKAGVEAGRGLWEFRTAEGAEFTVGQSINVDIFADVKKVDVTGTSKGKGFAGTVKRWNFRTQDATHGNSLSHRVPGSIGQNQTPGKVFKGKKMAGQLGNERVTVQSLDVVRVDAERNLLLVKGAVPGATGSDLIVKPAVKA
> >ID:WP_004160595.1|Erwinia_amylovora_01SFR-BO|01SFR-BO|50S_ribosomal_protei..|630|NZ_CAPA01000010(58437):26053-26682:-1
> MIGLVGKKVGMTRIFTEDGVSIPVTVIEIEANRVTQVKGLENDGYTAIQVTTGAKKANRVTKPAAGHFAKAGVEAGRGLWEFRTAEGAEFTVGQSINVDIFADVKKVDVTGTSKGKGFAGTVKRWNFRTQDATHGNSLSHRVPGSIGQNQTPGKVFKGKKMAGQLGNERVTVQSLDVVRVDAERNLLLVKGAVPGATGSDLIVKPAVKA
> >ID:WP_004160595.1|Erwinia_amylovora_01SFR-BO|01SFR-BO|50S_ribosomal_protei..|630|NZ_CAPA01000010(58437):26053-26682:-1
> MIGLVGKKVGMTRIFTEDGVSIPVTVIEIEANRVTQVKGLENDGYTAIQVTTGAKKANRVTKPAAGHFAKAGVEAGRGLWEFRTAEGAEFTVGQSINVDIFADVKKVDVTGTSKGKGFAGTVKRWNFRTQDATHGNSLSHRVPGSIGQNQTPGKVFKGKKMAGQLGNERVTVQSLDVVRVDAERNLLLVKGAVPGATGSDLIVKPAVKA
> >ID:WP_004160595.1|Erwinia_amylovora_01SFR-BO|01SFR-BO|50S_ribosomal_protei..|630|NZ_CAPA01000010(58437):26053-26682:-1
> MIGLVGKKVGMTRIFTEDGVSIPVTVIEIEANRVTQVKGLENDGYTAIQVTTGAKKANRVTKPAAGHFAKAGVEAGRGLWEFRTAEGAEFTVGQSINVDIFADVKKVDVTGTSKGKGFAGTVKRWNFRTQDATHGNSLSHRVPGSIGQNQTPGKVFKGKKMAGQLGNERVTVQSLDVVRVDAERNLLLVKGAVPGATGSDLIVKPAVKA
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your expected output but shouldn't be:
"if *letter* in str(record.seq):"
instead of
"if *letters* in str(record.seq):"

Comment: What is the desired output ? I'm guessing you want to replace all the B, Z, J, U and O's from your sequence with an X. If that's so, you must take the `outFile.write` outside the loop no ?

Also, are you sure you want to remove B ? (I mean they mean something in standard IUPAC code).

Comment: The desired output I can obtain but for each letter in letters, it is writing the same line 6 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is replace the ambiguous [IUPAC amino acid codes](http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/iupac.html) (plus some additional letters that you have somehow gained?) with `'X'`.

Better to use `str.translate()` (in Python 3) to do all your replacements at once. Also, since you're using Biopython to read the file, you can also write the output file easily with Biopython.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

letters = ["B", "Z", "J", "U", "O"]
trans_tab = str.maketrans(''.join(letters), 'X'*len(letters))

def yield_seqs(in_file):
    for record in SeqIO.parse(in_file, 'fasta'):
        record.seq = Seq(str(record.seq).translate(trans_tab))
        yield record

SeqIO.write(yield_seqs('input.fasta'), 'output.fasta', 'fasta')
```

Example:

```
$ cat input.fasta 
>1
MBZJ
$ python3 myscript.py
$ cat output.fasta 
>1
MXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

```
if letters in str(record.seq):
```

instead of

```
if letter in str(record.seq)
```

so, your check always fails, and prints the `else` part for every single letter.

Comment: This will still write the output multiple times though and not with all replacements conducted